# Неправильная кодировка в сообщении об ошибке

Tags: php

Установил apache 2.4 на windows. Закинул 2 файла index.html и parser.php. Оба файла в UTF-8. в файле index.html стоит , но все равно не могу прочитать ошибку из-за кодировки. Пробовал в httpd.conf написать AddDefaultCharset utf-8; - не помогло. Как и где мне выставить кодировку?[image: неправильная кодировка]

Comment: «Оба файла в UTF-8» — как вы это проверяли?

Comment: В Sublime в правом нижнем углу пишет кодировку файла.

Comment: тег meta установлен с кодировкой для html страниц?

Comment: Я так подозреваю, винда возвращает текст ошибки в кодировке cp866 (или cp1251), и никакие прописывания utf-8 нигде не помогут в данном случае. А вот что поможет, я увы не в курсе

Comment: Стоит html 5 meta
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">...

Comment: @Артем попробуйте временно поменять на cp1251 или cp866. Кодировка остальных текстов страницы сломается, но зато может текст ошибки станет возможно прочитать

Comment: AddDefaultCharset utf-8; а после этого сервак перезапускал?

Comment: да. Добавил самой первой строкой, потом AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .php .txt .js пробовал. Ноль эмоций.

Comment: Может дело в AJAX?